# PHP & HTML <a href> leaving extra space?

Tags: php, html

I have the following PHP code

```
$links = fopen("./links/links.txt", "r");
if ($links) {
    while (($line = fgets($links)) !== false) {
        $linkData = explode(" ", $line);
        /// The line below is the problematic one
        echo "<a href='".$linkData[0]."' class='links-item'>".$linkData[1]."</a><br>";
    }

    fclose($links);
} else {
    die('Error opening file, try refreshing.');
}
```

You can see I've seperated the line I'm having issues with. I have the following file `links.txt`

```
http://example.com Example

http://example2.com Example2
```

Basically this will add the URL in the text file to an anchor tag, and it'll add the text next to it, as the anchor display text. It works, but for some reason, every anchor tag ends with a space, except the last one. Anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: `fgets()` includes the newline in its result.

Comment: Why is there an empty line in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets()` captures newlines as well as word characters into the string. Use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove unwanted whitespace:

`echo "<a href='".trim($linkData[0])."' class='links-item'>".trim($linkData[1])."</a><br>";`

Alternatively, as @Barmar noted, you could use [`fgetcsv` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 4):

The string that `fgets()` returns includes the newline that separates the lines. This will be at the end of `$linkData[1]`, so you're writing

```
<a href='http://example.com' class='links-item'>Example
</a><br>
```

to the output.

You could instead use `fgetcsv()`, specifying space as the field delimiter. This will explode the line for you and automatically ignores the newlines.

```
while (($linkData = fgetcsv($links, 0, " ")) !== false) {
    echo "<a href='".$linkData[0]."' class='links-item'>".$linkData[1]."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: Not very important but if you can provide a max line length, replace the 0 in `fgetcsv` with it.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var_dump($linkData);
```

To see what does fgets() returns. Maybe there are unexpected characters.

Consider to use more advanced file formatting, for example you can use csv format and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php to retrieve results from file.